The navigator.share() method "title" is taking the "text" data on IOS
I'm implementing a feature, which is using the navigator.share API.
While the navigator share is available, I only want the text property, so I only specified this one in the shareData.
On IOS only, the problem is, when I click on the google or outlook app, the email body is well populated with the text, but the email object is also populated with the text property when it should be empty.
While clicking on the native IOS email app, the object is empty as desired.
Here is a link for testing on a real device: https://codepen.io/MarinFa/pen/QWRgjpy
I've tried:
const shareData = {
   text: contents.socials,
}

const shareData = {
   title: '',
   text: contents.socials,
}

const shareData = {
   title: null,
   text: contents.socials,
}

const shareData = {
   title: '\u200B',
   text: contents.socials,
}

